# Is this a modifier for noun clause or a coordinate clause?

Tags: conjunctions, poetry

```
Enter, stranger, but take heed 
Of what awaits the sin of greed, 
For those who take, but do not earn, 
Must pay most dearly in their turn. 
So if you seek beneath our floors 
A treasure that was never yours, 
Thief, you have been warned, beware 
Of finding more than treasure there.
```

(Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

It seems like ‘*For those ~ in their turn*’ is a modifier for the previous noun clause: *what awaits the sin of greed*. Is this right parse? Or do I need to think otherwise?

Comment: *For* here is a conjunction = approximately "because", not a preposition. "Don't be greedy: you will have to pay for what you take."

Comment: @StoneyB, I don’t understand your comment yet. You tell me ‘Don't be greedy, because~”. But is it not more natural “Take heed of something for those ~”?

Comment: Substitute _because_ for _For_ in line 3. It won't scan, but the sentence will parse better. _For_ introduces the whole clause in lines 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand *for* as a preposition taking *those who take, but do not earn* as its object and modifying the nominal  *the sin of greed*.

Let's do a little grammatical reduction here. Replace the nominal *what awaits the sin of greed* with X and the nominal *those who take, but do not earn* with Y. That leaves:

> Take heed of what awaits X for Y ...

But that leaves a dangling VP *must pay most dearly in their turn*.  What is its subject?

It can't be X, which is singular, because *their* tells us it has to be plural. Consequently the only available referent is Y, *those who take ...*.

> Take heed of what awaits X for Y must pay ...

But that means that Y plays an impossible double role as both object of the preposition *for* and subject of the clause *Y must pay*. If *for* is a preposition, its object would have to be not Y but the entire finite clause *Y must pay ...*. That makes no sense at all.

And you cannot parse *for* as a subordinator, since that requires the verb in the clause it heads to be cast in the infinitive—and the modal *must* is defective, it has no infinitive form.

The only solution is that *for* here is not a preposition, but a [**coordinating conjunction**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/for_2), meaning approximately "because".

```
Take heed of   what awaits       the sin of greed  
Keep in mind   what comes after  being greedy

For      those who take,  but do not earn,         must pay most dearly 
Because  anyone who takes what he has not earned   must pay a high price
```

Comment: My X is not ‘the sin of greed’ but ‘what awaits the sin of greed’. And so my Y is ‘For those who take, but do not earn, must pay most dearly in their turn’. Thus, ‘Take heed of the punishment for those who take, but do not earn, must pay most dearly’.

Comment: @Listenever *For* here doesn't mean *The punishment [given to] those who take...". It means "You should keep in mind that greed has consequences, because if you act on that greed and steal the consequences will be very bad."

Comment: @Listenever You still have the problem: what is the subject of "must pay most dearly"?

Comment: @StoneyB, I just got the logic of your 'take heed of ~ for' and noticed the dangling of the VP. Thank you very much.